# Best approach to handle error from api and show dialog with flutter provider package

Tags: flutter, mvvm, provider

I have requestManager, baseDialog, success and error response but I don't know the flow to handle and show error when request to API response error.

below is my code but it's not the right way I guess.

```
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    HomeViewModel viewModel = context.watch<HomeViewModel>();
    viewModel.addListener(() {
        if (viewModel.error != null) {
            showDialog(
                context: context,
                builder: (BuildContext context) {
                    return DialogHelper(title: "Custom Dialog Demo");
                });
        }
    });
    return Container(
        child: _ui(viewModel, context),
    );
}
_ui(HomeViewModel viewModel, BuildContext context) {
    if (viewModel.loading) {
        return Center(
            child: Text("Loading"),
        );
    } else if (viewModel.error != null) {
        return Center(
            child: Flexible(
                child: Text(
                    viewModel.error.toString(),
                    style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.titleLarge?.copyWith(color: kErrorColor),
                ),
            ),
        );
    } else {
        return SafeArea(
            child: Column(
                crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                children: [
                    Flexible(
                        child: ListView.builder(
                            itemCount: viewModel.items.length,
                            itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                                return Card(
                                    child: Column(
                                        children: [
                                            Row(
                                                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
                                                children: [
                                                    Text(viewModel.items[index].id.toString()),
                                                    Flexible(
                                                        child: Text(viewModel.items[index].title),
                                                    ),
                                                ],
                                            ),
                                            const SizedBox(
                                                height: 20.0,
                                            ),
                                        ],
                                    ),
                                );
                            },
                        ),
                    )
                ],
            ),
        );
    }
}
```

During the viewModel init it will call to server

I just want the aproach or idea to handle and show dialog.

Answer (score 0):

You shold handle your API response, smthg like this:

```
Future<Response> makeApiRequest() async {
  final url = 'https://example.com/api';
  final response = await http.get(url);
  if (response.statusCode != 200) {
    throw Exception('Failed to load data');
  }
  return response;
}
```

Then call the `makeApiRequest` function and handle the response in the `HomeViewModel`. If the response is successful, set the data and loading states. If there's an error, set the error state.

```
class HomeViewModel extends ChangeNotifier {
  List<Item> _items = [];
  bool _loading = true;
  String? _error;

  List<Item> get items => _items;
  bool get loading => _loading;
  String? get error => _error;

  void loadData() async {
    _loading = true;
    _error = null;
    notifyListeners();

    try {
      final response = await makeApiRequest();
      final data = json.decode(response.body) as List<dynamic>;
      _items = data.map((itemData) => Item.fromJson(itemData)).toList();
      _loading = false;
      notifyListeners();
    } catch (e) {
      _loading = false;
      _error = e.toString();
      notifyListeners();

      showDialog(
        context: Navigator.defaultRouteName,
        builder: (BuildContext context) {
          return AlertDialog(
            title: Text('Error'),
            content: Text(e.toString()),
            actions: [
              TextButton(
                child: Text('OK'),
                onPressed: () {
                  Navigator.of(context).pop();
                },
              ),
            ],
          );
        },
      );
    }
  }
}
```

I hope no one will judge me for links to my own articles. You can read more from [this](https://medium.com/full-struggle-developer/making-flutter-and-rest-api-work-together-states-of-the-asynchronous-operation-part-3-143e2af0ee76) and [this](https://medium.com/full-struggle-developer/making-flutter-and-rest-api-work-together-code-review-part-5-5969364654ca).

Comment: Yeah, I see, it's the same as I did and your code does not show dialog until the user click button error right?

Comment: What I want is when makeApiRequest response error UI will stop loading and show dialog immediately.

Comment: @Sekny updated. something like that?

Comment: Obviously, we using MVVM it mean all UI should be in view not in ViewModel :|